# pushbutton stops functioning when setting stylesheet in PyQt5==5.15 but not in PyQt5==5.14.2

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

When running my GUI using PyQt5==5.15, if I set the stylesheet for a QPushButton using .setStyleSheet(...) during in the **init** the button does not execute the connected function. If I do not set the stylesheet (# the .setStyleSheet(...) line), the button executes the connected function. If I am running PyQt5==5.14.2 the button executes the function with or without setting the stylesheet. Does anyone know why this would be? I am running MacOS 10.15.6, see this minimal example I pulled from my GUI:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class namedGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Title')
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 1050, 625)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
    
        self.namedButton = QPushButton('Button1', self)
        self.namedButton.setStyleSheet('font : bold 14px ; color : rgb(255,184,20) ;  background-color : rgb(0, 77, 159)')
        self.namedButton.move(5, 5)
        self.namedButton.clicked.connect(self.named_Button_function)
        
        self.namedButton2 = QPushButton('Button2', self)
        self.namedButton2.setStyleSheet('font : bold 14px ; color : rgb(255,184,20) ;  background-color : rgb(0, 77, 159)')
        self.namedButton2.move(175, 5)
        self.namedButton2.clicked.connect(self.named_Button_function)
        
        self.namedButton3 = QPushButton('Button3', self)
        self.namedButton3.setStyleSheet('font : bold 14px ; color : rgb(255,184,20) ;  background-color : rgb(0, 77, 159)')
        self.namedButton3.move(350, 5)
        self.namedButton3.clicked.connect(self.named_Button_function)
        
        self.show()

    def named_Button_function(self):

        dirname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
        
        print('Directory = ' + str(dirname))

            
def main_func():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = namedGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()
```

Comment: Newer versions are always worse and have more bugs. My advise is to never upgrade anything. I've seen plenty of questions about strange behavior from more recent versions of Qt that simply work as expected on my setup (PyQt5 5.9.2, Python 3.6, macOS 10.10).

Comment: UPDATE: I have nine buttons, if I comment any one or any multiple of the .SetStyleSheet(...) for the buttons, they ALL work, not just the one button that no longer has .SetStyleSheet(...). If I use .SetStyleSheet(...) for all of the buttons, none of them work. I updated the minimal example to have three buttons. As is, none of the buttons work for me. If I # any of the .SetStyleSheet(...) lines they all work. alec i'm guessing your answer will still hold but any ideas for a workaround? A hidden phantom button didn't work